# quickbooks web connector "edit" function

Tags: php, quickbooks, devkit

I am using the quickbooks PHP web connector and am able to send new customer data to quickbooks desktop. However I couldn't find any documentation on editing a customer(i.e. I want to send an edit done on the web application to the qb desktop). Is this possible to do in the web connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending new customer data to QuickBooks is almost identical to sending updated data to QuickBooks.

If you refer to the OSR:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

You can look up the qbXML syntax for:

- `CustomerMod`

And you'll see that really the only huge difference is that you have to specify these two fields:

```
<ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- required -->
<EditSequence >STRTYPE</EditSequence> <!-- required -->
```

So your request will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <CustomerModRq requestID="15">
      <CustomerMod>
        <ListID>ABCD-1365684445</ListID>
        <EditSequence>1365684445</EditSequence>

        <Name>Test Customer UPDATED</Name>
        ... more fields here ... 
      </CustomerMod>
    </CustomerModRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

That's taken from this site with more examples:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests

And if you take the time to *post your code* so we can see what you've done so far for `CustomerAdd` then we can give you more details about how to move forward and modify it to get it so you can send the above request.

Comment: Thanks Keith! I am using the sample code from the consolibyte site to enqueue the add customer to the queue like  $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $id_value); And using _quickbooks_customer_add_request to send the qbxml to qb desktop. If I am trying to send edit function to qb desktop, is there such an interface available to me ?

Comment: If you *post your code* I could help you more. Unfortunately, you *haven't posted your code* so it's impossible to guide you further.